# What is the replacement for SslSocketConnector setPort() in jetty http client?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I'm currently doing an upgrade of our **jetty** version from **7.1.6 to 7.6.2**. I noticed that a lot of the methods of SslSocketConnector that we're currently using have been deprecated since our old release.

From what I have seen in some other SO questions, I've managed to replace most of the methods by using `SslContextFactory` instead.

**However, I can't seem to find any equivalent of `SslSocketConnector`'s `setPort(int)` method. Any ideas on what the corresponding method for `SslContextFactory` is?**

The code before upgrading the jetty version:

```
theSSLConnector.setPort(theHTTPSPort);
theSSLConnector.setKeystore("key");
theSSLConnector.setPassword("OBF:password");
theSSLConnector.setKeyPassword("OBF:password");
theSSLConnector.setTruststore("trust");
theSSLConnector.setTrustPassword("OBF:password");
```

And after:

```
SslContextFactory theSSLFactory = new SslContextFactory();
// Port goes here?
theSSLFactory.setKeyStorePath("key");
theSSLFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("OBF:password");
theSSLFactory.setKeyStorePassword("OBF:password");
theSSLFactory.setTrustStore("trust");
theSSLFactory.setTrustStorePassword("OBF:password");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve it by using my already existing `SslContextFactory` as an input parameter to the `SslSocketConnector` constructor:

```
SslContextFactory theSSLFactory = new SslContextFactory();
theSSLFactory.setKeyStorePath("key");
theSSLFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("OBF:password");
theSSLFactory.setKeyStorePassword("OBF:password");
theSSLFactory.setTrustStore("trust");
theSSLFactory.setTrustStorePassword("OBF:password");

SslSocketConnector theSSLConnector = new SslSocketConnector(theSSLFactory);
theSSLConnector.setPort(theHTTPSPort);
```

Comment: I tested this way with Jetty 7.4 and `setKeyStorePath` is named `setKeyStore` and it must be set. Unlike its SslSocketConnector cousin, it does not default to the user's home directory.